# block chain return the money back to the clients

Tags: solidity

I have this code (payable function):

```
function() payable inTime at_stage(Stages.InProgress) 
active
{
    require(totalTokens <= totalTokensCapMax);

    require(token.isWhiteListed(msg.sender));

    require(msg.value>=minAcceptedAmount);

    totalTokens = safeAdd(totalTokens,safeMul(msg.value, intermedfinalConvRateETH));

    totalEtherContributed = safeAdd(totalEtherContributed,msg.value);

    insertToInvestorsArray(msg.sender);

    investedAmount[msg.sender] = contributor({
      amount:safeAdd(investedAmount[msg.sender].amount,msg.value),
      coin:"ETH"
    });
    beneficiary.send(msg.value);
    Contribution(msg.sender, msg.value, totalTokens);
}
```

now, the Crowdsale end without success.
how do I retrieve the ETH back to the clients? from the beneficiary account?

because now, only the beneficiary holds the money now - not the contract.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to use [OpenZeppelin's RefundVault](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/crowdsale/RefundVault.sol).

The idea is to have a separate contract from the Crowdsale that hold funds while the crowdsale is ongoing.

Once the crowdsale finishes successfully the owner can transfer the deposited amount to the main benefitiary.

If the crowdsale didn't reach it goals it allows each investor to retrieve its
contribution.